# mySQL, replacing nth value with a new value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with MySQL, I need to replace every nth occurrence of `<p>` with `</p><p>`.

I have the following which replaces all `<p>` tags with `<p></p>`. However I need to update it so it only updates on the second or greater occurrence of `<p>`.

```
UPDATE dnname.products
SET description = REPLACE (description, '<p>', '<p></p>')
```

As an example, a current value in description might look like this:

```
<p>test<p>test2
```

I need it to look like this

```
<p>test</p><p>test2
```

Coincidentally I need to insert `<p>` at the start of each value, and insert  `</p>` at the end of each value. But that's for a different query.

Comment: can you provide some sample data and the result after the replacement ?

Comment: Hi, I've updated with the output I require. Thanks

Comment: Cut leading <p> and training </p>. Then replace all <p> with </p><p> and add the leading <p> and trailing </p> back

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all occurrences and then remove the first.  In all honesty, this is probably easier using multiple updates.  But, something like this:

```
UPDATE dnname.products
    SET description = REPLACE(description, '<p>', '<p></p>');

UPDATE dnname.products
SET description = INSERT(description, LOCATE('<p></p>', description), 7,
                         '<p>', '<p></p>')
WHERE description like '%<p></p>%';
```

You can combine these into a single update:

```
UPDATE dnname.products
    SET description = INSERT(REPLACE(description, '<p>', '<p></p>'),
                             LOCATE('<p></p>', REPLACE(description, '<p>', '<p></p>')), 7,
                             '<p>', '<p></p>')
    WHERE description LIKE '%<p>%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a native mysql function that will be able to do this, but you could export the field or table and try using a sed replacement and then importing that back in.

There are more elegant solutions but you could do something like

```
mysqldump tablename > table.sql
```

Once you have that you can replace the `<p>` with `<p></p>`

```
sed 's/<p>/<p></p>/g' table.sql > almost-fixed.sql
```

Then you want to fix up the first bit again (a bit of a there and back-again solution

```
sed 's/^<p></p>/<p>/g' almost-fixed.sql > fixed.sql
```

Then run it back in

```
mysql yourdatabase < fixed.sql
```